# Kivy draw on a widget

Tags: python, widget, kivy

I am new to Kivy and after I have done the tutorials my next step was to add the two tutorial's widgets in one application. The class CombWidget will be my Widget to which the Paint and PingPong widgets will bne added to. For an intermediate step a BoxLayout was added and

1. a few Buttons
2. MyPaintWidget

in the BoxLayout.

To restrict the drawing only to MyPaintWidget a if statement was added

```
def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]
```

The line are drawn only to a small spot just above the buttons. The dot are draw everywhere except on the Buttons. The Buttons also don't react to clicks any more.

The code:

```
from random import random
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget

class CombWidget(Widget):
    pass
class MyPaintWidget(Widget):

def on_touch_down(self, touch):
    color = (random(), 1, 1)
    with self.canvas:
        Color(*color, mode='hsv')
        d = 30.
        Ellipse(pos=(touch.x - d / 2, touch.y - d / 2), size=(d, d))
        touch.ud['line'] = Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

def on_touch_move(self, touch):
    if self.collide_point(touch.x, touch.y):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

class MyPaintApp(App):       
    def build(self):
        return CombWidget()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

and the layout file:

```
#:kivy 1.7.0


<CombWidget>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        padding: 20
        spacing: 50

        MyPaintWidget:
            size: 100000, 100000
            size_hint: 100000, 100000

        Button:
            text: "Hallo"
        Button:
            text: "Hallo 1"
        Button:
            text: "Hallo 2"
```

To increase the size of MyPaintWidget I used the size: and size_hint: parameters in the kv file but not success.

Can anybody help met to increase the size of MyPaintWidget so that that area behaves just like the MyPaintyApp the in tutorial. Also why does my buttons show when you click on them.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to modify the layout file

```
<CombWidget>:
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    size: root.size
```

also by adding 'return True' to the methods on_touch_down and on_touch_move, everything worked.